# Storing a canvas context and editing attributes later

Tags: javascript, canvas

I feel like I may be misunderstanding canvas contexts however I am sure something like this must be possible.

I am making a game of chess. This chess game is based on a canvas.

When creating a chess 'piece' I run the following code (Within a class for the piece):

```
draw (canvas_id) {
    let canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillText(this.text, this.point.x, this.point.y);
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

I then at a later date want to be able to translate this item. There are multiple of these across the canvas. What I have done is :

```
move (diff_x, diff_y) {
    this.ctx.translate(diff_x, diff_y);
}
```

`this.ctx` does return a context but the translation does not have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated or alternative solutions.

Comment: You need to declare the canvas and the context only once. Declaring the canvas and the context inside a function that will be called many times is a mistake.

Comment: @enxaneta How would I reference each individual 'piece' and translate them individually?

Comment: Your whole canvas should be re-drawn every time something changes. Then, you don't need to translate anything in the canvas. You just update the stored position, and you re-draw all your elements on it. Each piece could draw it's own piece, so you'd have a main draw function that draws the background, then call the draw method of each piece.